# Henon Map Equation Trekker

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, packages

I am trying to make an Equation Trekker for the Henon map in the following way:

```
Needs["EquationTrekker`"]
EquationTrekker`Nesting;
Nesting /: 
InitializeGenerator[Nesting, f_, dvars_, {ivar_, ivmin_, ivmax_}, opts___] := Nesting[f, f, {ivar, dvars}]
Nesting[forig_, f_, vars_]@"Variables"[] := vars
Nesting[forig_, f_, ___]@"Display"[] := f;
Nesting[forig_, f_, ___]@"DisplayMode"[] := "Points";
Nesting[forig_, f_, ___]@"FormatTrek"[iv_, dv_, _] := dv;
Nesting[forig_, f_, vars_]@"ChangeParameters"[prules_] := 
Nesting[forig, forig /. prules, vars]
Nesting[forig_, f_, ___]@"GenerateTrek"[X0_, {iv0_, ivmin_, ivmax_}, ___] := 
Module[{n = Round[ivmax - iv0]}, NestList[f, X0, n]]
myfun[a_, b_][{x_, y_}] :=Block[{xnew = y + 1 - a x^2}, {xnew, b[xnew]}]
EquationTrekker[myfun[a, b], {x, y}, {iteration, 0, 1000},TrekGenerator -> Nesting, TrekParameters -> {a -> 0.3, b -> 0.3},PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-3, 3}}]
```

Most of these are default for Nesting in equation trekker. But then, these errors appear:

```
PropertyValue::pvobj: canvas is not an object with properties. >>
PropertyValue::pvobj: trekPane is not an object with properties. >>
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{canvas,canvasPane,All},Name->trekPane]) (1) >>
PropertyValue::poi: -- Message text not found -- (PropertyValue[{trekPane,trekController,All},Name->trekController]) (1) >>
```

which are rather annoying since I do not really know how to handle them.

If anyone knows what is wrong with this code, or if there is a better way to do it I would be grateful.

I actually wanted to take a plot of the Henon map for different choices of the parameter values, so if there is another way I really would like to see how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you on? (As an aside, that package badly needs updating; GUIKit has been deprecated for quite a while.)

Comment: @J.M. I am on 10.3. When I load it, it runs fine though, no error until the time for the trekker comes :)